# Android Checkbox button as Vector API 19

Tags: android, vector, android-support-library, android-drawable, android-checkbox

I'm trying to use CheckBox with 2 vector drawables in selector as button, but it gives me `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector` on API 19. From what i understand there's no direct support for vector drawables in API < 21, but other views have support options like `app:srcCompat`, is there anything like that for CheckBox? Or is the only option changing my selector to `.png` or just using 2 `ImageView`'s instead?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_state"
        android:checked="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView_ID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Room_topView_ID" />
```